# Which calculus textbook is this?

Tags: calculus, reference-request, book-recommendation

I found an image of a calculus textbook which implies this textbook must be a fun read. If anyone has gone through this book or remember reading please let me know. Thanks.

Here is the image:

[image]

Answer (score 1):

It seems to be taken from a textbook written by professor Chester Miracle, University of Minnesota:
http://www2.math.umn.edu/directory/details/296/

I can't confirm the name of the textbook. He has two books called Calculus for Engineering I and II published by Kendal Hunt with copyrights in 2016. Your picture shows up in sources on the internet as old as 4 years ago.

Comment: is there a link on some site where I can get pdf or buy it?

Comment: @Departed I don't know which book it is unfortunately and he doesn't seem to provide any public notes or syllabus for any of his teaching.

Answer (score 0):

I agree that this matches the format of Chester Miracles's textbooks. When I took the course, the books were purchased from Alpha Print in Dinkytown:

http://alphaprintandcopy.com/

I believe the courses were 1371 (Calc 1) and 1372 (Calc II)